# calling Hotbits web api and parse the xml answer file and print out the random numbers

Tags: c#, xml

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }
        static async Task<string> GetProductAsync(string path = "https://www.fourmilab.ch/cgi-bin/Hotbits.api?nbytes=8&fmt=xml&npass=1&lpass=8&pwtype=3&apikey=HB18CsHhr5Muzoee1KAu4QY5xUe")
        {
            string product = string.Empty;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
            }
            return product;
        }
        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            string str = await GetProductAsync();
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(str);
            Console.WriteLine(xml.InnerXml);
            XmlNodeList list = xml.GetElementsByTagName("random-data");
            string[] strs = list[0].InnerXml.Split(' ');
            foreach (object e in strs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

Hi, this is my source code in c# to call hotbits API and the error I got is

> "CData elements not valid at top level of an XML document. Line 1, position 3"

It is greatly appreciated if anyone can help.

Comment: Your API key is visible

Answer (score 0):

Try following using Xml Linq :

```
const string URL = "https://www.fourmilab.ch/cgi-bin/Hotbits.api?nbytes=8&fmt=xml&npass=1&lpass=8&pwtype=3&apikey=HB18CsHhr5Muzoee1KAu4QY5xUe";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);

    string randomNumbers = (string)doc.Descendants("random-data").FirstOrDefault();

    int[] numbers = randomNumbers.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",numbers.Select(x => x.ToString())));
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: BTW, you publicly released your API key

Comment: It is not my key, it is the OPs key.  I just modified the OPs posted code.

Comment: Oh. <<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>